# Como evitar Excepción no controlada al realizar operaciones en C#

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de realizar una operación entre valores Ceros, en este caso Division

```
obj.valUnitario_costo = valorUnitario / iva;
```

dado que tengo valores ceros en las variables me genera una excepción, cabe aclarar que los tipos de datos de mi variables son decimales ambos

Mensaje de Error

> Intento de dividir por cero

que puede hacer para que no me genere la excepción?

Teniendo en cuenta que se puede generar las siguientes situaciones.

1: Los valores de las variables pueden ser cero.

2: El valor de la variable `valorUnitario != 0` Y `iva = 0`.

3: El valor de la variable `iva != 0` Y `valorUnitario = 0`.

los valores que están en las variables en tiempos de producción no los conozco, es decir pueden variar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si conoces que las variables pueden tomar un valor de cero, y tambien que al dividir obtienes un exception, entonces validalo previamente

```
public void button1_ click(...)
{
    if(iva == 0){
       MessageBox.Show("El iva debe ser un numero mayor a cero");
       return;
    }

    obj.valUnitario_costo = valorUnitario / iva;
}
```

de esta forma ya no tendras el problema

---

Si las variables puede tomar cero entonces usarias

```
public void button1_ click(...)
{
    decimal result = 0;

    if(iva > 0){
       result = valorUnitario / iva;
    }

    obj.valUnitario_costo = result;
}
```

la idea es que no puedes hacer el calculo si el divisor es cero, por eso el valor de la operacion por defecto sera cero

Si lo quieres en una linea

```
obj.valUnitario_costo = iva > 0 ? valorUnitario/iva : 0;
```

Comment: el dilema @leandro es que el iva, puede ser cero y igualmente el valorUnitario

Comment: ehh pero imagino que matematicas conoces no? si es asi sabes que no se puede dividir cero

Comment: si, es claro. Lo que pretendo indicar es que no me genere excepción cuando sean ceros, si no por el contrario el valor de valUnitario_costo, sea cero o el valor contenido en la variable valorUnitario

Comment: He editado la pregunta, para hacer dar a conocer las situaciones que se pueden presentar

Comment: edite la respuesta, analiza el segundo ejemplo, pero basicamente se basa en que debes validar los datos de las variables antes de realizar la dicision

Comment: no importa el valor de la variable `valorUnitario` esa puede ser cero, el tema es la variable `iva` esa es la unica que debes validar

Answer (score 2):

puedes intentar condicionar tu operación para que siempre se cumpla las condiciones para realizar tu operación

ejemplo:

```
obj.valUnitario_costo = (iva!=0)?valorUnitario/iva:0;
```

Comment: porque tan complicado? si lo unico importante para el calculo es que la variable `iva` no sea cero, despues el resto aplicas la formula

Comment: Ha de generar el siguiente error: El operador && no se puede aplicar al tipo de operando bool y decimal